# goczmq not working even after installing through vcpkg

Tags: go, zeromq, czmq

I tried using goczmq on windows 10, but it doesn't work even if I installed czmq using vcpkg.

Steps I tried was:
`vcpkg install czmq` which automatically installed `zeromq` as well.

It seems to work on visual studio 2022, but not for `goczmq` which returns the following error.

```
....\github.com\zeromq\goczmq@v4.1.0+incompatible\auth.go:4:10: fatal error: czmq.h: No such file or directory
    4 | #include "czmq.h"
      |          ^~~~~~~~
```

Not sure if I missed some steps or if I need to do something extra?